# Nginx in front of keycloak and local microservices

Tags: nginx, keycloak, netflix-zuul, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup nginx + keycloak to protect my spring boot microservices.

I hope to config the following structure

```
   internet ---https---> nginx --http--> keycloak and other protected microservices

                   keycloak <----http----> zuul and other microservices
```

I could not figure out how to set the nginx to correctly pass original https request to http backend servers

here are my configurations:
NGINX

```
server {

    listen        443 ssl default_server;
    server_name   localhost; 

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/localhost.key;

    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/ledgerrun.access.log;

    proxy_set_header        Host $host:443;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    # keycloak redirect 
    location /auth {
        proxy_pass       https://keycloak:8443;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://192.168.1.15:15700;
    }

    # all /lr-servies redirect to 15700
    #location ~* ^/lr-(.*) {
    #    proxy_pass        https://192.168.1.15:15700;
    #}
}
```

Keycloak instance opens 8443 for https and 8080 for http.

Spring Cloud Zuul config as the following

```
server:
  port: "15700"

keycloak:
   auth-server-url: "https://my.external.ip:8443/auth"
   realm: "LedgerRunCTP"
   public-client: true
   resource: gateway-service
   security-constraints[0]:
     authRoles[0]: "user"
     securityCollections[0]:
       name: "internal services"
       patterns[0]: "/swagger-ui.html"
```

1. I have to configure the "auth-server-url" to https, since client need to login with keycloak first and that requires https for non-local connection. Is there a way to just use http for keycloak?
2. with above configuration, once keycloak authenticated the user, gets the following error:

   The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

What is the correct configuration to set it up to achieve

> 1. only https to nginx
> 2. all http behind nginx